# Derivative of a definite integral: $F(t) = \int_0^t \sqrt{1-x^8} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives, definite-integrals

I'm preparing for my Calculus 1 exam and I've stumbled across the following exercise, which I am not able to solve. Any help will be appreciated.

a) Find the domain and the derivative of the following function: $\displaystyle  F(t) = \int \limits_0^t \sqrt{1-x^8} dx $ .

b) Find first three nonzero terms of the Maclaurin sequence that is equal to F(t).

Comment: For $a)$, use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. i.e, if $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)\mathop{dt}$, then $F'(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: For the first one, can a function be integrated outside its domain? And the integrand is continuous, so it's integrable on every interval contained in its domain. Also check the fundamental theorem of calculus. For b), just find enough derivatives.

Comment: Here is a hint.  I tried to correct the title to "Derivative of a definite integral".  But the system said this was not allowed, since there is already a question with that exact title.  Maybe that other question will help you????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus states that if $f$ is a continuous, real-valued funtion defined on $[a,b]$, and $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt$, then $F'(x)=f(x)$. Then, the derivative of your function should be $\sqrt{1-t^8}$. Your function is only defined on the closed interval $[-1,1] \in \mathbb R$, since any other values render the integrand indeterminate.

The Maclaurin series is a Taylor series centered at 0. We have $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$$ So, find the first, second, and third derivatives at $a=0$, and plug them into this equation. You already have the first derivative, so set $t=0$. Then, $f^{(1)}(0)=1$, and the first term of the series is $\frac{1}{1!}(t-0)^1=t$. This is the term for $n=1$. The term for $n=0$ is simply zero, since $\int_{0}^{0}\sqrt{1-x^8}dx=0$. I will let you find the terms for $n=2$ and $n=3$.

Answer (score 1):

the domain of $\int_0^t \sqrt{1-x^8} \, dx$ is the domain of $\sqrt{1-x^8}$ which is the closed interval $[-1,1].$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus, the derivative $F'(t) = \sqrt{1-t^8}.$

$$F(t) = \int_0^x (1-x^8)^{1/2}\, dx = \int_0^t \left(1 + \frac12 (-x^8) + \dfrac{\frac12 \frac{-1}2}{2}(-x^8)^2 + \dots\right)\, dx\\
=t-\frac1{18}t^9+\frac1{136}t^{17}+\dots $$

Answer (score 0):

Try:
\begin{align}
F\left(t\right)&=\int_0^t f\left(x\right)\:dx\tag{1}\\
&= F\left(t\right)-F\left(0\right)\tag{2}\\
&=F\left(t\right)-\int_0^0f\left(x\right)\:dx\tag{3}\\
&=F\left(t\right).\tag{4}
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
F'\left(t\right)&=\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t f\left(x\right)\:dx\tag{5}\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\left[F\left(t\right)-F\left(0\right)\right]\tag{6}\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\left[F\left(t\right)-\int_0^0f\left(x\right)\:dx\right]\tag{7}\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}F\left(t\right)\tag{8}\\
&=F'\left(t\right).\tag{9}
\end{align}
In your case, let $f\left(x\right)=\sqrt{1-x^8}$, which gives us
\begin{align}
F\left(t\right)&=\int_0^t \sqrt{1-x^8}\:dx\tag{10}\\
&=\int_0^t f\left(x\right)\:dx,\tag{11}
\end{align}
and therefore
\begin{align}
F'\left(t\right)&=\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t\sqrt{1-x^8}\:dx\tag{12}\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\left[F\left(t\right)-\int_0^0\sqrt{1-x^8}\:dx\right]\tag{13}\\
&=f\left(t\right)\tag{14}\\
&=\sqrt{1-t^8}.\tag{15}
\end{align}

Comment: This is wrong...

Comment: @GEdgar Is it wrong now? I jumped the gun with that try :P Hopefully I didn't mess anything up. I re-wrote my answer. Hopefully it is better.

Comment: your statements are correct now, but I think you went overboard on detail.

Comment: @GEdgar Perhaps you are right about that. Thanks for looking it over again though, I appreciate it.